# Is it better to run 1 mile every day or 2 miles every other day or n miles every n days?

Tags: running, cardio

By better I mean for cardiovascular health.

Answer (score 1):

For cardiovascular health ,you must do either
(1) 10 minutes of high intensity interval training (HIIT) like running , brisk walk , Burpees etc everyday Or in total 40-50 minutes of high intensity workouts every week
OR
(2) 30 minutes of low impact exercises like walking , climbing stairs , yoga and stretches every day

**You have to be consistent to whatever exercises you’re doing, if you want better health.**

you must exercise 10 minutes every day instead of exercising heavily one day per month.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).